# One of my apache processes is huge - how can I find out why?

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi, memory-usage

I'm running Apache 2.2.12 with mod_wsgi, hosting a Django site.  Most of the apache child processes weigh in at about 125MB RSS, but occasionally I see one child balloon to > 1GB RSS.

At this point there's usually 1 huge process (>1GB), a couple of large ones (>500MB) and the rest are still ~125MB.  These are the mod_wsgi daemon processes.

I've tried using memory leak tracing in Python to see if it's the Django code, and I see no leaks.  Looking in the logs doesn't show any particularly strange requests.

I'm stumped on how to figure out what's causing this - any ideas?  Also, any workaround ways to kill the large apache process when it gets too big, without bringing apache down?

Some more details:

- Not using mod_php
- Using pre-fork

Answer (score 1):

Use [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) with [ExtendedStatus On](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html#extendedstatus) and see what that specific PID is doing.

Answer (score 0):

pmap -x pidofprocess

You can kill an apache child, but, that isn't a great solution.  Are you also running with mod_php? mpm-prefork?

Comment: pmap just shows one large anonymous allocation.  No clue there.